# Why is initial capacity important for deleting from ArrayList?

Tags: java

For my work I have done some tests for time chart.
I have come to something that surprised me and need help understanding it.

I used few data structures as queue and wanted to know how deleting is fast according to number of items. And arraylist with 10 items, deleting from front and not set initial capacity is much slower than the same with set initial capacity (to 15). Why? And why it's same at 100 items.

Here's the chart:
[image]

Data Structures: L - implements List, C - set initial capacity, B - removing from back, Q - implements Queue

EDIT:
Appending relevant piece of code

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run()
 {
  long time;
  final int[] arr = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000};
  for (int anArr : arr)
  {
    final List<Word> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    while (temp.size() < anArr) temp.add(new Item());

    final int top = (int) Math.sqrt(anArr);

    final List<Word> first = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<Word> second = new ArrayList<>(anArr);
    ...
    first.addAll(temp);
    second.addAll(temp);
    ...

    SystemClock.sleep(5000);

    time = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < top; ++i) first.remove(0);
    Log.d("al_l", "rem: " + (System.nanoTime() - time));

    time = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < top; ++i) second.remove(0);
    Log.d("al_lc", "rem: " + (System.nanoTime() - time));

    ...
   }
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: It is not clear how did you evaluate this times. Was it micro benchmark test? Where is it? You should provide some code to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article about [Avoiding Benchmarking Pitfalls on the JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html). It explains the impact of the Hotspot  VM on the test results. If you don't take care about it, your measurement isn't right. As you have found out with your own test.

If you want to do reliable benchamrking use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Answer (score 0):

I too was able to replicate it by creating the code below. However, I noticed that whatever is run first (the set capacity vs non-set capacity) is the one that will take the longest. I assume this is some kind of optimization, maybe the JVM, or some kind of Caching?

```
public class Test {



public static void main(String[] args) {
        measure(-1, 10); // switch with line below
        measure(15, 10); // switch with line above
        measure(-1, 100);
        measure(15, 100);
    }

    public static void measure(int capacity, long numItems) {
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

        if (capacity >= 1) {
            arr.ensureCapacity(capacity);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= numItems; i++) {
            arr.add("T");
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i <= numItems; i++) {
            arr.remove(0);
        }

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Capacity: " + capacity + ", " + "Runtime: "
                + (end - start));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah my code is pretty much same (in android environment).
But you are probably right, it's just cause it is first. However, answer is correct so I am accepting it. My tip is JVM, so if there is some JVM expert I would like to hear from him.